# Doubleclick listener on Vaadin Grid

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

How do I add a 2x click listener on a vaadin grid? 
When I 2x click on it, it takes me to another page. 
Example would be most appreciated.

Comment: This question doesn't meet Stackoverflow quality standards. Please refer to [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the MouseEvent you can simply ask for a double click.

See here [#MouseEvents.ClickEvent.html#isDoubleClick()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/event/MouseEvents.ClickEvent.html#isDoubleClick())

Comment: It only detects double-click if `setEditorEnabled(false)`. If it's true, the double-click event edits by default.

Comment: I think it also does not work if the grid is in selectionMode.MULTI

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
grid.addItemClickListener(listener -> 
    { 
       if (listener.getMouseEventDetails().isDoubleClick())
          // pass the row/item that the user double clicked
          // to method doStuff.
          doStuff(l.getItem());
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi @Brett, i'm using Vaadin 7 and trying to get Double click event for the grid, but i couldn't have getMouseEventDetails() method. Instead i have the isDoubleClick() method,  like below,
    grid.addItemClickListener(e -> {
  
   if(e.isDoubleClick()) {
    System.out.println("Double click");
   } else {
    System.out.println("Single click");
   }
 });
But, when i do double click, it's fall under single click only. How to overcome this issue.

Comment: @Pearl please have a look at the comment below the accepted answer. I think the described scenario is the same that you have. if you `setEditorEnabled(false)` then `e.isDoubleClick()` returns true.

Comment: @codinghaus, if there is any way to differentiate single click and double click if we set the setEditorEnabled(true).